# UPDATE MySQL using PDO, prepared statements and substituting tokens with bindParam; getting 'variables don't match tokens' error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I am attempting to UPDATE records within my MySQL database.

I build the prepared statement using arrays / loops:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE table01 SET ";  
        foreach($values as $value)
        {
        $sql .="$value = :$value, ";
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql,', ');    
        $sql .=" WHERE id = '$id'";
```

then I prepare this statement:

```
try 
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Then I bind each of the tokens / placeholders in the prepared statement to the values to be inserted using another loop:

```
foreach(array_combine($values, $variables) as $value=>$variable)
{
$stmt->bindParam(':$value', $variable);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

where $values is an array of column headers in the database (therefore ':$value' is a set of token names corresponding to them) and $variables is an array of variables containing data to be stored.

When I run this, I am given the error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

But as you can see I'm forming them from arrays - I've done counts on the arrays to ensure the elements match 1:1 and they do:

FYI:

```
$count1 = count($values);
$count2 = count($variables);

echo $count1;
echo $count2;
```

gives: 
    7575

(they both have 75 elements in them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes don't interpolate variables.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':$value', $variable);
```

should be

```
$stmt->bindParam(":$value", $variable);
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I guess every day's a school day! Yes in the example I was learning bindParam from they wern't using variables for both - makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnWoo, it's nothing specific to prepared statements; it's just that the name of the variable you're trying to bind will not match if you don't correctly handle the variable.  You can use whatever type of quote you want.

Comment: Needless to say @ElYobo this fixed my issue! I'll accept it in 8 mins when it let's me :) You are fast!